# Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (<class 'list'> c

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Below I would like to store the images in my laptop to the variable called X_data by using the function of `glob` and then split it into training and test set before testing the model.

```
 import cv2
 import numpy as np
 import tensorflow as tf
 from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import glob

 X_data = []
 files = glob.glob ("*.png")
 for myFile in files:
    image = cv2.imread(myFile)
    X_data.append(image)

 print('X_data shape:', np.array(X_data).shape)

import numpy
numpy.random.shuffle(X_data)
training, test = X_data[:80,:], X_data[80:,:]

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(training, labels_train, epochs=10, 
                                    validation_data=(test, labels_test))
```

But I'm getting

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'int'>"})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @desertnaut thanks for your edit, but the problem persists.. is there a problem because I don't specify X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test?

Comment: You do specify them, although with different names. First thing I would check is if you have integers in your arrays; if yes, try changing them to floats.

Comment: I have added the codes "training = training.astype(float) and test = test.astype(float)" but the problem persists.

Comment: Which line and variables are causing the problem.  A full traceback might help.  But you can also provide the `shape` and `dtype` of the relevant variables.  I'm guessing that `tesorflow` is objecting to an array with object dtype containing lists (and probably 1d).  Find that array and check the len of all its list elements.  Do any differ?  `np.array` makes an object array if it can't make a near multidimensional array from the inputs.

Comment: @hpaulj the error is in the `validation_data` (last line). `labels_test` returns a `[1]`. `type(labels_test)` returns a `list`. `len(labels_test)` returns a `1`. `Print(test)` returns a `[]`. `len(test)` returns a `0`. `type(test)` returns a `numpy.ndarray`

Answer (score 1):

I see couple of problems in your code:

1. Both `train` and `test` are `Lists`, not `Numpy Arrays`. Same might be the case with `Labels` (that part of code is not shared).
2. The part of code,

   `X_data = []
   files = glob.glob ("*.png")
   for myFile in files:
       image = cv2.imread(myFile)
       X_data.append(image)`

returns a `List of Strings`, rather than a `Numpy Array` of Floats and the code,

`training = training.astype(float)` and `test = test.astype(float)` will not resolve the issue.

```
['cat.373.jpg', 'cat.843.jpg', 'cat.970.jpg', 'cat.797.jpg', 'cat.786.jpg',
'cat.1.jpg', 'cat.172.jpg', 'cat.660.jpg'...........]
```

Is there any specific reason that you wanted to use the function, `glob.glob` to access the `Images` from the folders because there are better ways to do it.

One of the most efficient and optimized way to do this is to use `Keras` `ImageDataGenerator` and `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory`.

For example, if your `Image Data Directory` has Folders, each folder corresponding to each Class, as shown in the screenshot below,

[image]

Code to show how to use `ImageDataGenerator`, along with detailed explanation of every line of code is mentioned below:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, # Normalizes every pixel value
    validation_split=0.2) # Setting Validation Data as 20% of Total Data

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    Image_data_dir, # Traverses through all the Sub Folders (Category) inside this dir
    target_size=(img_height, img_width), # Sets the Image Size
    batch_size=batch_size, # Generates batches of `batch_size`
    class_mode='categorical', # Will Consider Labels as Categorical
    shuffle = True, # Shuffles the Data
    subset='training') # Considers 80% as training data

# Since we don't have separate directory for Validation Data and since we want the Total Data to be Partitioned, we should use "train_datagen"
validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    Image_data_dir, # Should use the Same Dir as Training for Splitting
    target_size=(img_height, img_width), 
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle = True, # Shuffles the Data
    subset='validation') # Considers 20% as Validation data

# Then you can train the model using the code mentioned below
model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // batch_size,
    validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // batch_size,
    epochs = nb_epochs)
```

Hope this solves your problem. If you still face any error, please share the complete code along with the error trace.

Happy Learning!